How to get the increment and decrement value in div element values with same name & div section
I am clicking + up to '35' then I click the add button. I want it to print the result: '35'. If I continue clicking incrementing it up to '40' and then pressing again the add button I need the code to print the result as '40'.
However that is not what my code is doing. Could you give me a hand?


$('.dec').click(function() {
  var inputValue = $(this).next().val();
  var newValue = parseInt(inputValue) - 1;
  if (newValue >= 30) {
    $(this).next().val(newValue);
  }
});

$('.inc').click(function () {
    $(this).prev().val(+$(this).prev().val() + 1);
});

function extraDish(extradishPrice, extraID, extraTitle) {
  var extraDishcount = $('.extraDishcount').val();
  console.log(extraDishcount);
}
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 pb-6">
  <div class="list-card bg-white h-100 rounded overflow-hidden position-relative shadow-sm">
    <div class="p-3 position-relative">
      <div class="list-card-body">
        <h5 class="mb-1 text-center fw-bold"><a href="#" class="text-black extraTishTitle">Raja</a></h5>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12 float-end">
        <div class="d-flex p-3">
          <span class="count-number">
            <button type="button" class="btn-sm left dec btn btn-outline-secondary"> 
              <i class="feather-minus">-</i> 
            </button>
            <input class="count-number-input extraDishcount" id="extraDishcount" name="extraDishcount" type="text" value="30" readonly="">
            <button type="button" class="btn-sm right inc btn btn-outline-secondary"> 
              <i class="feather-plus">+</i>
            </button>
          </span>
          <span class="ms-auto">
            <button type="button" onclick="extraDish('1.00','27','Tofu Sambal (+$1.00)')" class="btn btn-outline-secondary btn-sm buttonAdd">ADD</button>
          </span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 pb-6">
  <div class="list-card bg-white h-100 rounded overflow-hidden position-relative shadow-sm">
    <div class="p-3 position-relative">
      <div class="list-card-body">
        <h5 class="mb-1 text-center fw-bold"><a href="#" class="text-black extraTishTitle">Malar</a></h5>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12 float-end">
        <div class="d-flex p-3">
          <span class="count-number">
            <button type="button" class="btn-sm left dec btn btn-outline-secondary"> 
             <i class="feather-minus">-</i> 
            </button>
            <input class="count-number-input extraDishcount" id="extraDishcount" name="extraDishcount" type="text" value="30" readonly="">
            <button type="button" class="btn-sm right inc btn btn-outline-secondary"> 
              <i class="feather-plus">+</i>
            </button>
          </span>
          <span class="ms-auto">
            <button type="button" onclick="extraDish('0.80','30','Sambal Goreng ($0.80)')" class="btn btn-outline-secondary btn-sm buttonAdd">ADD</button>
          </span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>




It's not clear from your description what the problem is. I assume from the context of the snippet that I added, that you want to have the inc/dec buttons work on each input independently?

@Rory McCrossan. Yes you are right, when i an clicking add button i needs to print the inc/dec values

try update value by using closest(). for example when you click minus you should get correct element like this $(this).closest('.count-number').find('.extraDishcount').val(NEW_VALUE);

You have HTML elements with the same id attribute value. That is not valid in HTML. id attribute values should be unique.

I have no idea what you want actually. You don't want to add the 1 in +$(this).prev().val() + 1;? Is that what bothers you?

@ trincot,increment and decrement functionality working fine, my problem is when i am click add button that time i needs to print the incremented value

There's a few issues in your code, and some things which can be improved.

Remove the line $('.extraDishcount').val(pax);; as this is setting the the same value in all inputs whenever you increment the value
Remove the duplicate id attributes in your HTML. These values must be unique and cannot be repeated.
Traverse the DOM to find the .extraDishcount element related to the clicked 'Add' button, don't select all of them and change their values.
Use unobtrusive event handlers, as you do for the inc/dec buttons, not inline ones as you are for the 'Add' button. You can use data attributes to store required metadata in the HTML which you can read when the event fires.
Use Math.max() to set a minimum value for the decrement operation.
Use the function callback of val() to set the value, instead of separate getter/setter calls.

Here's an updated example with the changes made:


$('.dec').on('click', e => {
  $(e.currentTarget).next().val((el, i) => Math.max(30, --i));
});

$('.inc').on('click', e => {
  $(e.currentTarget).prev().val((el, i) => Math.max(30, ++i));
});

$('.buttonAdd').on('click', e => {
  const $btn = $(e.currentTarget);
  const price = $btn.data('price');
  const id = $btn.data('id');
  const name = $btn.data('name');
  const extraDishcount = $btn.closest('.row').find('.extraDishcount').val();
  console.log(extraDishcount, price, id, name);
});
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 pb-6">
  <div class="list-card bg-white h-100 rounded overflow-hidden position-relative shadow-sm">
    <div class="p-3 position-relative">
      <div class="list-card-body">
        <h5 class="mb-1 text-center fw-bold"><a href="#" class="text-black extraTishTitle">Raja</a></h5>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12 float-end">
        <div class="d-flex p-3">
          <span class="count-number">
            <button type="button" class="btn-sm left dec btn btn-outline-secondary"> 
              <i class="feather-minus">-</i> 
            </button>
            <input class="count-number-input extraDishcount" name="extraDishcount" type="text" value="30" readonly="">
            <button type="button" class="btn-sm right inc btn btn-outline-secondary"> 
              <i class="feather-plus">+</i>
            </button>
          </span>
          <span class="ms-auto">
            <button type="button" data-price="1.00" data-id="27" data-name="Tofu Sambal" class="btn btn-outline-secondary btn-sm buttonAdd">ADD</button>
          </span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 pb-6">
  <div class="list-card bg-white h-100 rounded overflow-hidden position-relative shadow-sm">
    <div class="p-3 position-relative">
      <div class="list-card-body">
        <h5 class="mb-1 text-center fw-bold"><a href="#" class="text-black extraTishTitle">Malar</a></h5>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12 float-end">
        <div class="d-flex p-3">
          <span class="count-number">
            <button type="button" class="btn-sm left dec btn btn-outline-secondary"> 
             <i class="feather-minus">-</i> 
            </button>
            <input class="count-number-input extraDishcount" name="extraDishcount" type="text" value="30" readonly="">
            <button type="button" class="btn-sm right inc btn btn-outline-secondary"> 
              <i class="feather-plus">+</i>
            </button>
          </span>
          <span class="ms-auto">
            <button type="button" data-price="0.8" data-id="30" data-name="Sambal Goreng" class="btn btn-outline-secondary btn-sm buttonAdd">ADD</button>
          </span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>



